# "Invalid toke" and "signature invalid" errors with OAuth2 request

Tags: php, oauth, oauth-2.0, http-headers, httprequest

I was wondering if someone might be able to point out where my request is getting messed up. I am trying to connect using OAuth2 but I am getting a weird error.

I have tried playing around with some of the header options but to no avail. For some reason I think it's something simple I am getting wrong. I am just getting started with OAuth2.

It is returning:

```
array(5) {
  ["access_token"]=>
  string(88) "//43773esO1jYyy4hEZ0EXjovF21uqvIQC5U4TzLf8b+LhLf/fYnw3i5bMNkFTiynTZdIvNO9mlW90QhcKLuxg=="
  ["token_type"]=>
  string(3) "mac"
  ["secret"]=>
  string(88) "tCAU89rpW9RGoF28EHufUuLG1GBA+CquUuPqh9svQ9Y8ofkqucpMnt+9X9pqgYgE6GBalBwKGNTerMcCDqh5lA=="
  ["algorithm"]=>
  string(12) "hmac-sha-256"
  ["expires_in"]=>
  int(3599)
}
E3Bgu19tbvYKEwMLv7p6rgUfKFMHgudBm4hOUMcBCOI=
string(65) "{"error":"invalid_token","error_description":"Signature Invalid"}"
```

Here is my script:

```
 <?php 

  $identifier = "QSJMuz3wGIMBbeL6rciemeIJSZ7H5fnuQgU5urztijK6DkFCxLW0FDgqIRraTPW7PiehKM+5mi+U9S45ORGA4igJfmVlv0w0WqNGQ1Rz4v2wakbt26HyVrJg/0ybE0KQMB0qjL/jj3xwOBkPA1FmU1x612axwPY1yMEZYHB9FhfUinFEdhSTd2alSpr5YgJlZDwZ6IK6Z2JaDYOP0S2e3A==";
 $decrypted_id = "dTBFdjlqVStXc1BYN2hSUE1lZVY2QWdaWWI2SjlTdG9nNnVtVUgrb04wb1dpeWhtdUZKT1FIUEZmSW1GeDNpa2xjZnpJWTU1d2FmQVIwMlhlVldTN0E9PTpxVXpHSXdYQVJldG82dGplMnU2YzZBPT0=";

  $r = rand(0, 25);
  $arr = explode(':', base64_decode($decrypted_id)); 
  $p1 = $arr[1];
  $p0 = $arr[0];

  $res = base64_encode($p1 . ":" . $p0);  

  $headers = array('Authorization: Basic ' . $res);
  $posts = array('unique_id', $decrypted_id . ':' . $r);

  $ch = curl_init();

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://ishin-global.aktsk.com/auth/sign_in");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);  

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($posts));
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);  

  $server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
  $server_output = json_decode($server_output, true);
  echo "<pre>";
   var_dump($server_output);
  echo "</pre>";

  curl_close ($ch);


?>

 <?php 

  $access_token = $server_output["access_token"];
  $secret = $server_output["secret"];

  $ts = time();
  $nonce = $ts . ":" . uniqid();

  $url = "https://ishin-global.aktsk.com/user";
  $url_host = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);

     $msg = implode('', array(
        $ts,
        $nonce,
        'GET',
        $url_host,
        '/user',
        '443'
      ));



  $byte_array = base64_decode($secret);
  //echo $byte_array;
  // Create signature
  $mac = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', utf8_encode($msg), $secret, true));

  echo $mac;    

  $headers = array('Authorization: Id="' . $access_token . '", Nonce="' . $nonce . '", Ts="' . $ts .'", Mac="' . $mac . '"');



  $ch1 = curl_init();

  curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL,"https://ishin-global.aktsk.com/user");

  curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
  curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false); 
  curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.52 Safari/537.17');
  curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true); 
  curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true); 

  echo "<pre>";
   $server_output1 = curl_exec($ch1);

   if(curl_errno($ch1)){
    echo 'Request Error:' . curl_error($ch1);
   }

  var_dump($server_output1);
  echo "</pre>";

  curl_close ($ch1);



 ?>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's two years later, but the port instead of 443 is 3001

The way you are doing it, is very different of my approach, so I don't know if there's something wrong in your code, for me it seems so, but I do not know where those two variables came from.

I use this to create the OAUTH2

```php
$rn=chr(0x0A);
$secret=$signin['secret']; //this is from sign_in part that I assume you're getting right
$nonce=$requestepochtime.':'.md5('whateveryouwant');
$method='GET';
$url='/blablabla';
$hostname='the-url-without-the-http';
$port='3001'; //<- THIS ONE DROVE ME CRAZY
$RFC2616_string=
    $requestepochtime.$rn.
    $nonce.$rn.
    $method.$rn.
    $url.$rn.
    $hostname.$rn.
    $port.$rn.
    ''.$rn;
```

If you solved it at that time, maybe in global now you have to face the puzzle image.